# How to reply and update the right notification

Tags: android, push-notification

The problem: I just always got last notification ID when I reply to notification, it updates the last created notification, even I reply to first or other than the last created notification.

So when I update notif_1, I got updated notif_4(last notif)

So when I update notif_2, I got updated notif_4(last notif)

What I want is when I reply to notif_1, to update the notif_1 not from other notif

```
public static void setAndUpdateNotificationMessage(Context context, CharSequence[] history, CharSequence message, CharSequence title) {

        String replyLabel = ("Your message here...");
        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
                .setLabel(replyLabel)
                .build();
        Intent replyIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
//        replyIntent.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, 1);
        replyIntent.setAction(REPLY_ACTION);
        replyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent replyPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                        requestCode,
                        replyIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_reply_icon,
                        ("Reply"), replyPendingIntent)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                        /*for wear watch notification*/
                        .setAllowGeneratedReplies(true)
                        /*for wear watch notification*/
                        .build();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .addAction(action)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        if(history != null) {
                builder.setRemoteInputHistory(history);
        }

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);


        notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Comment: I think there is mis-match in 'id' field that you provide while "notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());"  How do you generate/assign this 'id'? It should be unique every-time.

Comment: ID is unique every time, I change it with 'id' from  user that send a message. I have different notification every time when different user send a message or if the same user send another message the right notification is updated with the new message.
But problem comes when I Reply in the notification, every time the last received notification is updated.